# Visual studio code ctrl + ~ doesn't open terminal in KDE plasma

Tags: visual-studio-code, kde-plasma

Currently on Ubuntu I'm running KDE version 5.18.8, and I've just started coding in Visual Studio Code, but when toggling the console, I just get an old notification on the top right corner of my screen informing me how old it is, not using the shortcut entirely.

[image: Visual studio code with a notification open in the top right]

*(I toggled the terminal manually in the settings)

Is this a shortcut I have to change in vscode or KDE? Since there isn't anything online I can seem to find for this. It's a bit of an annoyance.

Comment: You have to modify the keymaps in your KDE plasma settings

Comment: @Ian Thanks :D, KDE is much more overwhelming than gnome.

Comment: I'm more of a KDE guy : )

Comment: @Ian I went through my keyboard shortcuts and I couldn't find anything that matches the combination of keys, is there a difference between keymaps and keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: What keyboard layout do you use, can you try US?
Can you try recent KDE Plasma version?